# How do I correctly map Azure CDN endpoint to Angular 7 Project in blob storage container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have been trying to create Azure CDN endpoint to blob storage container for an Angular 7 Project.

Following steps were followed.

1. Crated a standard, HOT LRS Blob storage.
2. Under created blob, created a container with access to blob anonymous read access.
3. Uploaded dist/* to container.
4. Created CDN Profile with Standard Verizon
5. Created an endpoint with origin hostname set to point 1 above and orgin path to blob container.

Now, My Endpoint Hostname looks `https://<myendpoint>.azureedge.net`

When I navigate to this link from the browser nothing default XML displays.
When I navigate to `https://<myendpoint>.azureedge.net/<blobcontainer>/index.html`, index page displays but ends with `net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

It trying to download supporting files such as `styles.hash.css, runtime.hash.js` etc from the path `https://<myendpoint>.azureedge.net/` not from the path `https://<myendpoint>.azureedge.net/<blobcontainer>/` so as these files do not exists, I get this error.

How do I correctly map Azure CDN endpoint to Angular 7 Project in blob storage container?

What I tried?

1. I removed `orginpath` to my endpoints
2. Blob container access to anonymous for blob and containers
3. I did `purgeall` multiple times

Update: Same is working in Azure VM's IIS at port XX and virtual directory in E:\XX

Here is my dist/index.html as generated by angular cli.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.5/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
<!-- Other CDN content -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.d53c073df9bdc9d8dc56.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root> </app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.e34dbbfe0677512b179e.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.24a4835bc4e54cff0563.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.3d2c3408bf112b226574.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also many blogs suggest to toggle on static web site at blob storage account but I did not find such option in Azure Portal --> Storage Account --> Blob or in Blob --> Container.

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with the HTML file as to how the CSS and JS files are referenced in there. What happens when you directly access the file through storage URL?

Comment: Both storage url and endpoint url gives me same error where as iis in azure vm and my localhost both works well. I am just planning to shift Angular from VM's IIS to blob.

Comment: 2 things: 1) Please edit your question and include the HTML file code (especially the portion where you're referencing CSS/JS files. 2) In your VM, is the app running at root level or is it running in a virtual directory?

Comment: updated with your 2 points.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding static website, the storage account should be v2. You should see an option under settings. Regarding HTML file, does your JS file are in the same place as your index.html? Also, will it be possible for you to share the actual storage URL?

Comment: Created another storage account with v2 and marked as static website, now it is working as expected. Thank u.

Comment: Awesome! However, please ensure that you understand the pricing for v2 storage accounts. In my experience, v2 storage accounts are more expensive than v1 storage accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just narrow down the comment as an answer to this question for more references.

Azure Storage **General Purpose v2 accounts** allow you to serve static content (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and image files) directly from a storage container named `$web`.
You can upgrade your current storage account to V2 following `Settings--->Configuration--->upgrade` in the Azure portal, then you can see the `Static website` option in the Settings of storage account.

Next, upload your assets to the `$web` container via the Azure portal.

To configure a CDN endpoint for this static website, except **storage** option, you also can select the **custom origin** as the `origin type`. If so, you can put primary endpoint hostname like `storageaccount.z19.web.core.windows.net` in the static website as the `origin hostname`.

For more reference: [Static website hosting in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website)